# What the right LINQ TO SQL syntax

Tags: sql-server, select, linq-to-sql

what is the right LINQ TO SQL or SQL server syntax for this statment

```
Select ProductName
from Products 
where ProductId = (Select ProductId 
                   from OrderAndProducts        
                   where OrderID = 5 )
```

Comment: There's no reason to do a subquery here, as this is logically a join. See Andrew's answer. I'd do the SQL of this as `SELECT p.ProductName FROM Products p, OrderAndProducts o WHERE p.ProductID = o.ProductID AND OrderID = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linq To Sql

```
int orderId = 5;

var result = (From p in context.Products
join op in context.OrderAndProducts on p.ProductId equals op.ProductId
where op.OrderId == orderId
select p.ProductName).ToList();
```

context will be your data context from linqToSql.

I'm not quite sure what you mean about SQL Server syntax - does that query not already work?

Comment: Maybe add `int orderID = 5;` and change `where op.OrderID == 5` to `where op.OrderID == orderID` to generalize it a little.

Comment: i meant sql syntax to write on new query on sql server.
But your solution works when i use it once, but if i try to add a new Product to order i gor fail msg "Sequence contains more than one element"

Comment: Do you mean there is more than one order associated with a product?  That query should only ever return a single item, or a default of NULL so I am not sure how you are getting that message

Comment: the association is Many Products to An Order. 
the query should run each time im adding a new product to that Order

Comment: Assuming your associations are built, you should be able to eliminate the explicit join here and just have it in your model. Thus `var result = from p in context.Products where p.OrderAndProducts.Any(op => op.OrderId == orderId) select p.ProductName`

Comment: You can also flip the logic and start with the child record: `var result = from op in context.OrderAndProducts where op.OrderId == orderId select op.Product.ProductName`